# Defining order of appearence in geom_boxplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this data.frame:

```
df = data.frame(x = c(1,1,2,2,3,3), factor = c("crb","crb","ctx","ctx","bsl","bsl"), factor.level = c("pat","mat","pat","mat","pat","mat"), factor.level.color = c("blue","red","blue","red","blue","red"), ymin = c(0.031,0.152,0.071,0.026,0.051,0.032), lower = c(0.119,0.522,0.415,0.185,0.287,0.285), middle = c(0.298,0.701,0.615,0.384,0.500,0.499), upper = c(0.477,0.880,0.814,0.584,0.714,0.714), ymax = c(0.848,0.870,0.874,0.929,0.967,0.950),stringsAsFactors=F)
```

and I'd like to plot it in a `geom_boxplot` so that `df$x` defines the x-axis location, `df$ymin`, `df$lower`, `df$middle`, `df$upper`, `df$ymax` define the boxes, `df$factor` defines the x-axis ticks labels, df$factor.level.color defines the color of the boxes, and `df$factor.level` should appear in the legend (unique values). A pair of boxes should be plotted on the same x-axis location. For this reason a transparency factor needs to be defined

This is an improvised version of how I want it to look like:
[image]

(obviously the x and y axes tick values are missing)

I thought this code is that I need:

```
pl = ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x)) + geom_boxplot(aes(lower = lower,upper = upper, middle = middle, ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax,color = factor.level.color, fill = factor.level.color),
      position = position_dodge(width = 0), width = 0.5, alpha = 0.5, stat = "identity") + scale_fill_identity("factor level", guide="legend", labels = df$factor.level) + 
      scale_color_identity("factor level", guide = "legend", labels = df$factor.level) + 
      scale_x_discrete(breaks = seq(1,length(unique(df$factor)),1), labels = unique(df$factor), limits = seq(1,length(unique(df$factor)),1)) + 
      labs(x = "factor",y = "fraction") + theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size = rel(0.8)), axis.title.y = element_text(size = rel(0.8)))
```

But the outcome is a bit messed up:
[image]

I guess levels need to be somehow defined but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: don't you have access to the data used to obtain those summaries?

Comment: You mean the ymin, lower, middle, upper, and ymax columns? I do, but I didn't think it is relevant. I had a similar question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22284740/user-defined-parameters-for-ggplot2-geom-boxplot) only there the colors were unique and here they are not, and I think that this is the reason my code doesn't work here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `aes(x = factor(x))` in the call to `ggplot(...)`

```
pl = ggplot(data = df, aes(x = factor(x))) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(lower = lower,upper = upper, middle = middle, 
                   ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax,
                   color = factor.level.color, fill = factor.level.color),
               position = position_dodge(width = 0), 
               width = 0.5, alpha = 0.5, stat = "identity") +
  scale_fill_identity("factor level", guide="legend", labels = df$factor.level) + 
  scale_color_identity("factor level", guide = "legend", labels = df$factor.level) + 
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = seq(1,length(unique(df$factor)),1), 
                   labels = unique(df$factor), 
                   limits = seq(1,length(unique(df$factor)),1)) + 
  labs(x = "factor",y = "fraction") + 
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size = rel(0.8)), axis.title.y = element_text(size = rel(0.8)))
```

[image]

Comment: exactly. 1 second before!

Comment: `position = position_dodge(width = 0.5)` would make it looks better